# What does "rewind" mean for buzzfeed.com/rewind?

Tags: word-meaning

I sometimes read BuzzFeed for fun.

I noticed a channel called https://www.buzzfeed.com/rewind

May I know what is the meaning of the "rewind" here?

I thought it should be a category or channel name like "Sports", "Shopping", "Education"....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BuzzFeed Rewind** defines itself as: Everything that's old.

In other words, you don't go to BuzzFeed Rewind for fresh news but for things that refer to past events.

The dictionary meaning of rewind is "a function of an audio or video recorder or player, as a cassette deck or DVR, that returns the audio or video incrementally to an earlier point.". Based on that you can conclude that BuzzFeed incrementally *rewinds time* and gives you old news from that period.

Comment: Is it a word created by Buzzfeed or just an ordinary English word?

Comment: @AGamePlayer It's an established usage. See https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCjnfXh2I3u0GAAHHrPe_PKw for instance.

Comment: thanks @Acccumulation